# Scraping game info in RetroPie

Tags: retropie

I've seen in some YouTube videos that when the user is navigating through the game menu, it displays info and an image about the game. The videos explain that to get that info, you must use scraping tool.

I've tried to do this but none of my games will download the info. I've tried using both available sites and changing different options, but with no success. I'm not in front of my Pi right now to test this again, but I believe it comes back and says "no games found", or something to that effect.

How can I fix this to scrape the game info? Also, how long does it take for this to complete?

Answer (score 2):

I found using [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) is an easier way to preform this task. First download the [scraper tool](https://github.com/sselph/scraper).

1. When in FileZilla transfer the "scraper" file into each roms folder you'll be using. Also while using FileZilla you need to create a directory in each folder named "images".
2. Once "scraper" is transferred to your pi's roms folder you need to change the permissions to 777 (this can be done in FileZilla by simply right clicking the scraper file.) in order for the auto scraping to work.
3. Once this task is finished ssh into your pi and navigate to each of your roms folder `cd /home/pi/RetroPie/roms/**system_name**`then run command `sudo ./scraper -thumb_only` Do this for EVERY roms folder the scraper file is in.
4. The timing all depends on how many roms are in each folder and this will give you game covers and descriptions on about 99% of your games. I hope this is the answer you were looking for!

Comment: Having read this I tried  that scraper for MAME games and it did an excellent job. I installed it from the Pi command line though.

Answer (score 0):

The main website EmulationStation uses for scraping is currently down as it's being moved (thegamesdb.net)

Sselph's scraper can be configured to use another source - see https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/wiki/scraper

Comment: `Steven Selph's Scraper` is the best scraper for me. Fast and easy to use. Just exit from Emulationstation so the script can write the info for each rom.